# How to avoid delay while sending mouse inputs inside mouse hook proc?

Tags: c++, winapi

Here's my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void InputRButtonDown()
{
    INPUT inp;
    inp.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    inp.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;

    SendInput(1, &inp, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void InputRButtonUp()
{
    INPUT inp;
    inp.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    inp.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;

    SendInput(1, &inp, sizeof(INPUT));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        WORD button;
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            break;

        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            break;

        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            break;

        case WM_XBUTTONDOWN:
            button = HIWORD(((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->mouseData);
            if (button == XBUTTON2) {
                InputRButtonDown();
            }
            break;

        case WM_XBUTTONUP:
            button = HIWORD(((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->mouseData);
            if (button == XBUTTON2) {
                InputRButtonUp();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    SetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, NULL, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != NULL) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
}
```

It should simulate right click when I'm clicking one of the mouse side buttons. The problem is that right mouse click triggers after a short delay (~400ms), not instantly. If I modify this code to call `InputRButton...` functions in keyboard hook proc instead of mouse hook proc, it works without any delays. Where's my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)

Comment: @rem: When was the last time you saw a system, where processing mouse input would take 400ms?

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I use keyboard SendInput in keyboard hook proc, it sends without delays. When I use keyboard SendInput in mouse hook proc, it sends without delays too. Delay is only occured when I use MOUSE SendInput in MOUSE hook proc. Only this combination.

Comment: @lem0nify a mouse generates more events than a keyboard. All those small delta movements, etc. Chances are, by the time you press a mouse button down, there is probably other events already in the mouse queue waiting to be processed ahead of your SendInput() events. Whereas when sending SendInput() events from a keyboard proc, the mouse is likely idle and its queue is empty.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, the delay is occured even when mouse is not moving. All I do is clicking XBUTTON2. Also, as IInspectable said, 400ms is too huge delay for processing mouse input. Autoclickers like AHK or AutoIt can do the same task without tangible delays. I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: @lem0nify it was just an idea. Other than not zeroing out the unused members of the `INPUT` structs, I don't see anything else wrong with the code shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I’ve tried with zeroing it out. No difference.

Comment: @rem: That's not how mouse events work. All those tiny delta movements get coerced into a single `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message the next time the application cares to ask **and** nothing else is left in queue to handle. `SendInput` generates messages that are **posted**, i.e. they are higher priority than `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. This isn't caused by some sort of delay due to regular event handling. It's more likely the result of internal logic, that needs to wait for some time to distinguish between two input events that share the same starting sequence.

Comment: @IInspectable WM_MOUSEMOVE is higher level, synthesized per app as requested. WH_MOUSE_LL is lower level, sitting just above Raw Input. So it is bound to see more events than app queues can see. But whatever. I'll stop now.

Comment: @rem: Nothing of that could ever explain a delay of half a second. That's a delay built into the system. Deliberately. Not something that happens because the system couldn't keep up. It's time the system needs to wait to make a final decision. Like it would when interpreting touch input, where a long press gets interpreted as a right-click. Which forces the system to delay left-click events until the long-press interval has elapsed (or the finger was lifted off of the digitizer surface, whichever happens first).